# How to reload data on data from another component?

Tags: angular

There are two placed components on the page:

```
<app-actions></app-actions>
<app-events></app-events>
```

In the first component I can add new event, in successful case it returns data from server. After that I need add this data into component `<app-events></app-events>`.

Both components use the same EventService for crud operations. So, how inform `<app-events></app-events>` to request data again from server when changes happen in `<app-actions></app-actions>`.

I know, I can use Input, Output.

I it good way to do that:

```
class EventService {
   private events: any[] = [];
   public constructor(
    private translate: Http
  ) {
        this.events = this.http.loadEvents();
    }

    public getEvents() {
      return this.events;
    }

    public addItemToEvents(event) {
       this.events.push(event);
    }

}
```

Then in template:

```
<div *ngFor="let i in getEvents()"></div>
```

What do you think?

Comment: You can use an observable within your service with both components subscribing to the observable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an Observable in your service where both the `app-events` and `app-actions` components subscribe to.  When ever you add a new event you can push the new values to the observable in which both components will receive the updated values.

> https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

---

#### event.service.ts

```
export class EventService {

  private eventsData: Events[] = [];
  private eventsSource: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.eventsData);
  public events: Observable = this.eventsSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  addItemToEvents(event: Event) {
    this.eventsData.push(event);
    this.eventsSource.next(this.eventsData); // sends updated array to subscribers
  }

}
```

#### actions.component.ts

```
export class ActionsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private subscription: Subscription;
  public events: Event[];

  constructor(private _eventService: EventService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this._eventService.events
      .subscribe(events => this.events = events);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.subscription) this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

#### events.component.ts

```
export class EventsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private subscription: Subscription;
  public events: Event[];

  constructor(private _eventService: EventService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this._eventService.events
      .subscribe(events => this.events = events);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.subscription) this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Comment: What is it: ` this.dataSource`?

Comment: sorry, the `this.dataSource` was a mistype.  I originally called the service DataService and renamed it to EventService because that's what you called your service.  Corrected issues

Comment: I also provided a link to the Angular docs that explain how to use a service to share data between components.